# Creating a search function for strings in Javascript - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a function which will search a specific words.

For example if I tap the letter "O" the first result will be the word "Oasis" (and not "U2 - Still Haven't Found What I'm..." and all the other songs that has "O" in their words), or any other middle word.
 It need to ignore spaces - " ", the char "-" (" "-" ") and ' or other chars, so it will connect all thw words together. 
 For example when I tap  "dontlookbackin" the search will find the word which is starting with the first letter I pressed, than the other letter in the word and so on.

So far I'm only able to make a simple search - to find every word that contains the first letter I pressed.

The specific part of the "search" function :

```js
 SearchSong = () => {
    console.log("Pressed")
    var e = this.state.searchRes;
    if (e == "") {
      return;
    }
    var musicList = [];
    var songs = [];
    if (this.state.songs != null) {
      songs = this.state.songs;  
       musicList = songs.filter(song =>
        song.Song_Name.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase())
      );
```

Example of the current search -
[image: The corrent simple search]

**If more detials and fixes are needed please tell me.**

Comment: What is the actual problem? Removing the spaces and such? Since the string 'Oasis - Don't Look Back In Anger' without spaces and in lowercase is 'oasisdontlookbackinanger', so your .includes() check should find it.

Comment: @Shilly I need it to find only the word which start twith the letter I pressed, than the second (the third and so on). As for now it don't ignore the chars and spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let strKeyword = "string001";
    musicList = [];
    songsLength = songs.length;

for (i = 0; i < songsLength; i++) {
    if (songs[i].Song_Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").substr(0, strKeyword.length).toLowerCase() == strKeyword.toLowerCase()) {
        musicList.push(songs[i]);
    }
}

console.log(musicList);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it should ignore the chars and " " in the search result not in the word I pressed.  still in progress, I updated my qustion. What if need numbers not to ignore them ?

Comment: You want to remove all the chars from the songs list, not from the search keyword, am I right ?

Comment: Yes I fixed this - `    if (this.state.songs[i].Song_Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").substr(0, strKeyword.length).toLowerCase() == strKeyword.toLowerCase()) { fixed it with numbers thanks. Can you tell me how to find from a middle word in the string?
` .

Comment: Updated the answer for skip numbers also. Please check.

Comment: middle word like ?

Comment: Middle as  - people are strange  (from : The Doors - People Are Strange)

Comment: For this, you can use `include` method to find occurrence as you've already used in your question.

Comment: I dont understand where to put in the code the 'inclueds' to find a whole 
 middle word

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184519/discussion-between-sup-dr-and-sagar-jajoriya).

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should get you started (see comments):

```
function removeUnwantedChars(str) {
    return str.replace(/\W/g, "");
}

function search(str) {
    // Create regex like "abc" becomes "^a.*b.*c"
    str = removeUnwantedChars(str);
    if (!str) {
        return [];
    }
    const searchRex = new RegExp(
        "^" +
        RegExp.escape(str.charAt(0)) + [...str.substring(1)].map(ch =>
            ".*" + RegExp.escape(ch)
        ).join(""),
        "i"
    );
    // Search for matches
    return songs.filter(song => searchRex.test(song.Song_Name.replace(/\W/g, "")));
}
```

...using a regex escape function along the lines of the ones in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/157247).

Live Example:

```js
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function(string) {
      return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    };
}

const songs = [
    {Song_Name: "U2 - I Still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For"},
    {Song_Name: "Oasis - Champagne Supernova"},
    {Song_Name: "Oasis - Don't Look Back In Anger"},
    {Song_Name: "The Rolling Stones - Like A Rolling Stone"}
];

function removeUnwantedChars(str) {
    return str.replace(/\W/g, "");
}

function search(str) {
    // Create regex like "abc" becomes "^a.*b.*c"
    str = removeUnwantedChars(str);
    if (!str) {
        return [];
    }
    const searchRex = new RegExp(
        "^" +
        RegExp.escape(str.charAt(0)) + [...str.substring(1)].map(ch =>
            ".*" + RegExp.escape(ch)
        ).join(""),
        "i"
    );
    // Search for matches
    return songs.filter(song => searchRex.test(song.Song_Name.replace(/\W/g, "")));
}

const testStrings = [
  "oasisdontlookbackin",
  "oasisanger",
  "therollstone",
  "rolling" // no match
];
for (const str of testStrings) {
  console.log(str, "=>", search(str));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The `.*` in the regex means "any number of any character here" which means that you don't have to type **every** significant character after the first one (which is why `"oasisanger"` works). But it does incorporate your requirement that the *first* character match the first character of the name.

Comment: That said, I'd drop the requirement that the user get the first character right. More flexible. But it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
song.Song_Name.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.toLowerCase())

Comment: I tried it, it worked(!) but I want to find also from a middle word. ( I edited the question).